# Statistics on the number of seats per car

Tags: transportation

I am looking for some data on the (average) number of seats per car. I know one could assume such number to be 5, but I would like to have some statistics to support such an assumption.

Comment: What about vans and trucks that have bench seats? How do you count those?

Comment: I'm behind the same question. I'm trying to figure outs how many car's seats are in the world. I found there are 1.2 billion vehicles (all categories including trucks, buses and off-road), 95% of them light duty vehicles.

Comment: javier - please add this as a comment, as it is not an answer

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you will find a statistics for this, but I assume it will be easy to do it by yourself. There are a few datasets out there that contains this info.

**The Comprehensive Cars (CompCars) dataset** [link](http://mmlab.ie.cuhk.edu.hk/datasets/comp_cars/index.html)

Each car model is labeled with five attributes, including maximum speed, displacement, number of doors, number of seats, and type of car.

**World Data Atlas** [link](http://knoema.com/atlas/topics/Cars/datasets)

This one includes several datasets related with cars and production. You could try some of them to see if they have the information you want.